# What datatype should be used here to Accept the response from the Server

Tags: java, android, object, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

I am making a **request** to the `Magento` **Server** using `XMLRPC` to get the details using `multiCall()` function.
I have achieved **success** in calling the `multiCall()` function as it **does not** results to any `Exception`.

I am using `Objects` to **send data** and when I use `Object` `DataType` to get the **response**,It gives the `Exception` like

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;
at org.xmlrpc.ProductService$doingBackTask.doInBackground(ProductService.java:94)
at org.xmlrpc.ProductService$doingBackTask.doInBackground(ProductService.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
```

**The code that I use to call is as followed:**

```
Object[] skuid=new Object[product_list.size()];
Object calling[]=new Object[product_list.size()];

for(int m=0;m<product_list.size();m++)
{
    skuid[m]=new Object[]{product_list.get(m).getp_Sku()};
    calling[m]=new Object[]{"catalog_product_attribute_media.list",skuid[m]};   
}

Object b[][];
try 
{
  // The Upcoming line causes Exception : java.lang.ClassCastException 
  b=(Object[][])client.callEx("multiCall",new Object[]{sessionId,calling});  
}
catch (XMLRPCException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is pretty much self-explanatory: the result of the `callEx` method call is of type `java.lang.Object` and you're trying to cast it to `String[][]`.

Obviously, the returned value is not of type `String[][]`.  Do you have the source of this `callEx` method?  If yes, I suggest that you dig into it to see what exactly it returns.

Comment: Aleks G...Me Hard luck..Actually I have edited it and made it to Object,just at the time you might be Answering to it.We both might be in the Edit Mode.Actually I was trying many different things before Putting the Question Here.And and it was the last thing here that I have tried..:))..Actually multiCall() is a API call that Magento provides.I don't have the Code.The call I have made will return list of URLS of the images of the products.But replacing it with the Object also Gives me the same Exception.

Comment: @HareshChaudhary Please show the code of `callEx` method - this is the one responsible for packaging the result.

Comment: Aleks G : It's an inbulit method provided by Android-XMLRPC library...but still I would like to give the like of the class you ask me..It's here..http://pastie.org/private/uidmu3pwrnhkmpc1tneq

Comment: @HareshChaudhary What is `iXMLRPCSerializer` in line `Object obj = iXMLRPCSerializer.deserialize(pullParser);`?  What class is this object of?  Is it your own class?

Comment: Aleks G : No,Actually that serialization and de-serialization is done by the Library...It's a class of the Library..If you want to view that class then please let me know..I will post it and give you a link for that...There is no problem with that I hope so because before calling this multiCall() function I have called many more methods..like login,call etc.

Comment: Aleks G : That Line you described De-Serializes the response that is received from the Server on the  Client side using that Library class.

Comment: @HareshChaudhary Yes, I understand that; it's specifically this line that produces the result different from the one you want.

Comment: Yes.But then I can't do any tampering with that class,as other calls that I make get De-serialize with an ease using that class. And tampering it would make their a problem.